# displaying move list in a memory match game

Tags: javascript

i am trying to display the moves list in a javascript memory match game, i need some help please,

```
card.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if (count<2) {
        count++;

        if (count===1) {
            firstGuess=card.dataset.name;
            card.classList.toggle('is-flipped')
        }else{
            secondGuess = card.dataset.name;
            card.classList.toggle('is-flipped')
        }


      if (firstGuess !== '' && secondGuess !== '') {


        if(firstGuess===secondGuess){

            setTimeout(match, delay);
           setTimeout(reset,delay);



          }else{
            setTimeout(reset,delay);
          }

      }


   }

})
```

how do i display the number of moves on the html page

Comment: Please give us your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//This variable will keep track of the count
let count = 0;
//This is the element that will display the count
const countEl = document.querySelector('#move-count');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', e => {
  count += 1;
  countEl.innerHTML = count;
});
```

```html
<div id="move-count"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add 1" />
```